# Getting a SIGABRT in Xamarin.Forms (iOS) when using camera initiated from website in a WKWebView

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, camera, wkwebview, zxing.net

I have a Xamarin.Forms app (XF 4.3.0.991211) VS2019 (16.4.5) XCode (11.3.1)

There is an existing web app that allows the user to take pictures of equipment before and after kinda of thing.  The XF app launches a WKWebView to view this site and the users are able to take pictures etc..., but sometimes, we get the following SIGABRT.  I "think" the user is taking pictures fast (and automatically uploaded/saved on the site) when this happens, but we cannot 100% reproduce the issue.

It seems the collection is getting mutated, but it is always when the user is in the WKWebView, so the XF app really has no control there.

The app does utilize ZXing for scanning barcodes with the camera.  But is disabled if it's not being used.

Does anyone know where to start looking, or has anyone run into this before?

```
SIGABRT: Objective-C exception thrown. Name: NSGenericException Reason: *** Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x28211cb10> was mutated while being enumerated. Native stack trace: 0 CoreFoundation 0x00000001ba310980 DC2C95C6-B954-39E8-86A2-5E0AF8801E87 + 1255808 1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x00000001ba029028 objc_exception_throw + 60 2 CoreFoundation 0x00000001ba3102d4 DC2C95C6-B954-39E8-86A2-5E0AF8801E87 + 1254100 3 libobjc.A.dylib 0x00000001ba03c1a4 objc_enumerationMutation + 32 4 CameraUI 0x00000001dc8f4f3c 289C074B-4FFE-3D83-927A-98B268DD914F + 229180 5 CameraUI 0x00000001dc8f499c 289C074B-4FFE-3D83-927A-98B268DD914F + 227740 6 Foundation 0x00000001ba6daffc 7A7A96AF-79E4-3DB1-8904-42E61CAE8999 + 1146876 7 CoreFoundation 0x00000001ba26899c DC2C95C6-B954-39E8-86A2-5E0AF8801E87 + 567708 8 CoreFoundation 0x00000001ba2689ec DC2C95C6-B954-39E8-86A2-5E0AF8801E87 + 567788 9 CoreFoundation 0x00000001ba267ce4 DC2C95C6-B954-39E8-86A2-5E0AF8801E87 + 564452 10 CoreFoundation 0x00000001ba26797c DC2C95C6-B954-39E8-86A2-5E0AF8801E87 + 563580 11 CoreFoundation 0x00000001ba1e0910 DC2C95C6-B954-39E8-86A2-5E0AF8801E87 + 10512 12 CoreFoundation 0x00000001ba2672ac _CFXNotificationPost + 1268 13 Foundation 0x00000001ba5c9b8c 7A7A96AF-79E4-3DB1-8904-42E61CAE8999 + 27532 14 UIKitCore 0x00000001be416fc4 AAFEFEBE-C172-3346-8972-810EB8F2F2C6 + 10784708 15 UIKitCore 0x00000001bddda500 AAFEFEBE-C172-3346-8972-810EB8F2F2C6 + 4244736 16 UIKitCore 0x00000001be416d70 AAFEFEBE-C172-3346-8972-810EB8F2F2C6 + 10784112 17 UIKitCore 0x00000001bdba8b38 AAFEFEBE-C172-3346-8972-810EB8F2F2C6 + 1944376 18 UIKitCore 0x00000001be059518 _UIScenePerformActionsWithLifecycleActionMask + 112 19 UIKitCore 0x00000001bdba8724 AAFEFEBE-C172-3346-8972-810EB8F2F2C6 + 1943332 20 UIKitCore 0x00000001bdba8154 AAFEFEBE-C172-3346-8972-810EB8F2F2C6 + 1941844 21 UIKitCore 0x00000001bdba8540 AAFEFEBE-C172-3346-8972-810EB8F2F2C6 + 1942848 22 UIKitCore 0x00000001bdba7dc4 AAFEFEBE-C172-3346-8972-810EB8F2F2C6 + 1940932 23 UIKitCore 0x00000001bda10078 AAFEFEBE-C172-3346-8972-810EB8F2F2C6 + 270456 24 UIKitCore 0x00000001be649e9c AAFEFEBE-C172-3346-8972-810EB8F2F2C6 + 13090460 25 UIKitCore 0x00000001be40da38 AAFEFEBE-C172-3346-8972-810EB8F2F2C6 + 10746424 26 UIKitCore 0x00000001bdfa78e8 AAFEFEBE-C172-3346-8972-810EB8F2F2C6 + 6133992 27 FrontBoardServices 0x00000001bf506068 370F1F18-E8A9-36B5-B0EB-9735A02CE2DE + 53352 28 FrontBoardServices 0x00000001bf52de04 370F1F18-E8A9-36B5-B0EB-9735A02CE2DE + 216580 29 FrontBoardServices 0x00000001bf510ef4 370F1F18-E8A9-36B5-B0EB-9735A02CE2DE + 98036 30 FrontBoardServices 0x00000001bf52dc6c 370F1F18-E8A9-36B5-B0EB-9735A02CE2DE + 216172 31 libdispatch.dylib 0x00000001b9fb5fd8 0C7A69CD-F2EE-3426-BFD8-742C903D3D07 + 12248 32 libdispatch.dylib 0x00000001b9fb8d1c 0C7A69CD-F2EE-3426-BFD8-742C903D3D07 + 23836 33 FrontBoardServices 0x00000001bf553254 370F1F18-E8A9-36B5-B0EB-9735A02CE2DE + 369236 34 FrontBoardServices 0x00000001bf552f00 370F1F18-E8A9-36B5-B0EB-9735A02CE2DE + 368384 35 FrontBoardServices 0x00000001bf55346c 370F1F18-E8A9-36B5-B0EB-9735A02CE2DE + 369772 36 CoreFoundation 0x00000001ba28c108 DC2C95C6-B954-39E8-86A2-5E0AF8801E87 + 712968 37 CoreFoundation 0x00000001ba28c05c DC2C95C6-B954-39E8-86A2-5E0AF8801E87 + 712796 38 CoreFoundation 0x00000001ba28b7c8 DC2C95C6-B954-39E8-86A2-5E0AF8801E87 + 710600 39 CoreFoundation 0x00000001ba286694 DC2C95C6-B954-39E8-86A2-5E0AF8801E87 + 689812 40 CoreFoundation 0x00000001ba285f40 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 480 41 GraphicsServices 0x00000001c4516534 GSEventRunModal + 108 42 UIKitCore 0x00000001be411580 UIApplicationMain + 1940 43 IRMobile.iOS 0x0000000103180fd0 _ZN7plcrash2MS5async24dwarf_cfa_state_iteratorIyxE4nextEPjPNS1_28plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_tEPy + 16210712 44 IRMobile.iOS 0x00000001030c000c _ZN7plcrash2MS5async24dwarf_cfa_state_iteratorIyxE4nextEPjPNS1_28plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_tEPy + 15420244 45 IRMobile.iOS 0x00000001030bff94 _ZN7plcrash2MS5async24dwarf_cfa_state_iteratorIyxE4nextEPjPNS1_28plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_tEPy + 15420124 46 IRMobile.iOS 0x0000000102272164 _ZN7plcrash2MS5async24dwarf_cfa_state_iteratorIyxE4nextEPjPNS1_28plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_tEPy + 421036 47 IRMobile.iOS 0x0000000102620bb4 _ZN7plcrash2MS5async24dwarf_cfa_state_iteratorIyxE4nextEPjPNS1_28plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_tEPy + 4282108 48 IRMobile.iOS 0x000000010526fbfc GMSx_AbslInternalSpinLockWake + 768728 49 IRMobile.iOS 0x000000010532c644 GMSx_AbslInternalSpinLockWake + 1541408 50 IRMobile.iOS 0x000000010533290c GMSx_AbslInternalSpinLockWake + 1566696 51 IRMobile.iOS 0x000000010524ddc8 GMSx_AbslInternalSpinLockWake + 629924 52 IRMobile.iOS 0x000000010540e3c0 xamarin_release_block_on_main_thread + 25212 53 IRMobile.iOS 0x000000010227059c _ZN7plcrash2MS5async24dwarf_cfa_state_iteratorIyxE4nextEPjPNS1_28plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_tEPy + 413924 54 libdyld.dylib 0x00000001ba104e18 9D122047-19B7-36A2-A892-27401F9E0E6C + 3608
```

Comment: Hi , you need to check which array occurs error first .Then re-create a temporary array that is exactly the same as the one you used. Use this temporary array to modify the original array.

Comment: That's how I would normally approach this type of this, however, the error happens while the user is in the WKWebView, navigated to a web app which allows the user to take pictures.  The app itself is not controlling the camera, the web app in the WKWebView is controlling the camera.